# Check If Transient Exists Without Retrieving the Whole Data in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to check if transient exists before retrieving the whole saved data?

According to this page, http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API, to check whether the saved transient value is successfully retrieved, the following code is used:

```
if ( false === ( $value = get_transient( 'value' ) ) ) {
     // this code runs when there is no valid transient set
}
```

But this is assumed that the retrieved data will be used if available. When hundreds of web pages are cached with the Transient API and need to be only checked if the cache is still there, it's not practical to retrieve all the data. I'm not sure how it affects the speed and memory but in general, the larger the size is, it gets slower and consumes more memories.

So I'm wondering if there is a simple way to only check if it is saved or not like the `empty()` function.

Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This only retrieves the expiration time.

```
$your_transient = 'your_transient';
$data_timeout = get_option('_transient_timeout_' . $your_transient);
if ($data_timeout < time())
    echo 'it is expired.';
else
    echo 'there is a transient';
```

Comment: If this solution is to be used for a plugin/theme, which is gonna run on different environments, You might face some issues with the site using APC or memcache.

Because, APC/Memcache stores data in memory, as a result there are fair chances that this snippet will always say that the transient is expired.

Answer (score 3):

if(!get_transient('value'))  should do the job, it checks if the transient exists or has expired.

Comment: It retrieves the data internally from the database. Are you sure it does not affect memories and server responses?